# SQL query to replace comma separated values in field with lookup from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table which has some data like this:

```
Id      Value
--     -----
1      A,C,D,E
2      A,B
3      E
```

I also have a lookup table:

```
Id     Value
---    -----
A      101
B      102
C      103
D      104
E      105
```

Using a sql statement, i want to convert the comma separated values into their respective value from the lookup table so the output will be:

```
Id      Value
--     -----
1      101,103,104,105
2      101,102
3      105
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing multiple values in a delimited string.

Comment: data coming from json as array of strings, which needs to be converted into given values to import into another system. out of my control

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: postgresql, oracle, mysql...?

Comment: Lots of answers to this in other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this script query bellow and change with your table to parse string to rows query

```
select regexp_substr('A,C,D,E','[^,]+', 1, level) as Value from dual
connect by regexp_substr('A,C,D,E', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

VALUE
A
C
D
E
```

After that join them with table lookup to get lookup value.

Comment: is this sql server syntax? i get error running it, and its not quite what i was looking for. i need it to look up the value by id from another table

Comment: If you using SQL Server can be follow this link 

https://anyonconsulting.com/business_intelligence/how-to-split-delimited-string-column-into-a-table-rows-in-sql-server-instance/

OR

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

It's the same my script.